# Where is the SharePoint object cache stored??

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

We have experienced a strange issue in SharePoint. We backed-up and restored a site collection from WebApp1 to WebApp2 and both the site collections have Publishing Features activated (BLOB CACHE was NOT Enabled)

After successful restore , none of the sites were working. Following Exception has occured :

> Site id <> could not be found OR File not found

Solution :

In the stack trace there method sitecachesettings(guid id).....Reset the IIS, and booom every thing works fine :)

My Question :

Where is object cache stored ??? how it works?? point me any links where I can dig in deep

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SharePoint object cache is stored in memory, which is why an IISReset clears it down. Depending on how you restored the site, I'd probably expect to need to do an IISReset after such an admin operation.

More details on object caching [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298466.aspx).

Comment: I assume when you say its memory it is infact the memory of the worker process...the two apps I mentioned in the question are running in separate worker processes..how did the restore affect the other worker process???

Comment: If you trigger an IISReset is clears all application pools' memory and kills all worker processes. If you only recycle one application pool without an iisreset then you only clear the object cache for that one web application.

Comment: Yep, agreed that's the reason the other worker processes were cleared down. One slight clarification I'd add to James' comment would be that a specific app pool recycle would clear the object cache for *all* web apps running in that app pool - could be more than one.

Comment: thanks every one...I was under the impression that they were different application pools...but I cross checked today and they were sharing the same application poool :)

Answer (score 0):

Are they running within the same application pool?

Comment: @dumb: the web applications re running in same applicatons pool...so sharing memory... I was under the impression that they were different application pools..thanks